# "Action not Defined" but it is

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

I apologize if this is just a misunderstanding on my part in how to use Laravel.

I'm learning Laravel and I'm building a small application, however, I try to make a form in a view to pass data to a Controller but I get the following message.

```
ErrorException
Action App\Http\Controllers\clientesController@confirmarEdit not defined. (View: (redacted)\laravel\resources\views\clientesEditar.blade.php)
```

This method is indeed defined in clientesController, where all the others controllers are defined and work:

```
public function confirmarEdit($id)
{
    ...
}
```

I'm using the LaravelCollective package to use forms, following th[e documentation which states I can use pass form data to Controllers](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#opening-a-form), I'm calling this method using a View, this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Modificar Cliente {{ $cliente[0]->id }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      {{Form::open(['action' => ['clientesController@confirmarEdit', $cliente[0]->id]])}}
      Nombre: {{ Form::text('cnom', $cliente[0]->nombre)}}
      Apellido: {{ Form::text('cape', $cliente[0]->apellido)}}
      Empresa: {{ Form::text('cnom', $cliente[0]->empresa)}}
      <input type="submit" value="Editar">
      {{Form::close()}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Calling the method from a Route works, but not if I call it from a view, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need to pass the `id` parameter? From the action definition it does not look optional...

Comment: You're right, I need to pass the id parameter, while testing I removed it from the form:open() method to test and I forgot to add it back. I edited the OP to reflect the proper flow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{ !! Form::open(array('action' => "clientesController@confirmarEdit", $cliente[0]->id)) !!  }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.

I still get the same error.

Comment: What version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: I use the latest version of Laravel.

Comment: When you installed that package, did you run **composer dumpautoload**? See my updated answer, try with the **!!**

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I ran composer dumpautoload then started the Laravel service again. Tried again with your method but now I have a different error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Sorry, it must be one bracket, not two. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => "clientesController@confirmarEdit", $cliente[0]->id)) !!}
```

Hope this work for you !!!